# Is it possible to take and evaluate values before to do submit with PHP?

Tags: php, form-submit

Imagine this scenario `bar.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="foo.php" method="POST">
            <label>Who was John Lenon?</label>
            A musician <input type="radio" name="answer" value="musician" /><br />
            An athlete <input type="radio" name="answer" value="athlete"  /><br />
            A builder <input type="radio" name="answer" value="builder"  /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I need to do is to determine if the answer is correct or not after the user clicks the submit button but before to go to `foo.php`.

I know that I can reach it in the next document (`foo.php`), but I want to do it in the same document (`bar.php`) without using Javascript, just with PHP.

So, is it possible to do it?

Comment: You could POST back to `bar.php` to validate the input, and then redirect to `foo.php`, but it may be better to not have `foo.php` at all and show all questions and answers in `bar.php` - assuming that `foo.php` shows the next question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="foo.php" method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

If myFunction() returns false, submission is cancelled, so if it checks out make sure to return true.  If answer needs verified serverside, you can do an AJAX request within myFunction().

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: only if you change the action to "bar.php"

**Long answer**:
If the action attribute of the form tag is set to "foo.php", all the information in the form will be sent directly to foo.php

bar.php will not be aware of the content of the form's input unless the forms action is set to bar.php.

In order to validate the input before sending it to "foo.php" you either use javascript (which you said you don't want), either you change the action's value to "bar.php", then in bar.php validate the input and then forward the values to foo.php